# Отображение фотографий с помощью Lightbox в Joomla

Tags: joomla, lightbox

Есть сайт на *Joomla 1.5*. Стоял компонент *Fabrik*, благодаря которому работала галерея *Lightbox*. После удаления *Fabrik* не работает галерея. Как можно восстановить работу галереи?

Comment: опять поставить компонент не пробовали?

Comment: он пропускает вирус. уже решили

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, ваше решение в виде ответа. возможно, оно поможет другим людям быстрее решить аналогичную проблему.